# MS C Compiler requires declarations of variables to be at the beginning of a function. Is that supported by the standard?

Tags: c

A common error is

```
'var' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is C89. in C99 you may declare them anywhere.

Comment: And Microsoft does not produce a C99 compiler.